# Is there any way to get rows that satisfy a relation between it's columns in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a MySQL table named `prices` which looks like:

```
Name  | price | amount | total
-------------------------------
name1 |  15   |   2    |  17   
name2 |  20   |   3    |  20
name3 |  25   |   4    |  29
name4 |  30   |   5    |  35
```

I want to get the names which specify that the sum of the price and amount is equal to the total, which are `name1` and `name3` in the previous table.

I already did that as SQL query like the following `SELECT Name FROM prices WHERE price + amount = total`.

Is any way to do it in Laravel Eloquent if I have a `prices` model?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think eloquent has some magic method for this. But you can always use `whereRaw` with eloquent as shown below:

```
Prices::select('name')->whereRaw('price + amount = total')->get();
```